# How to add JavaScript Flow annotation for returning instance itself?

Tags: javascript, annotations

I have the following es6 class:

```
// @flow
class MyClass {

  _active: bool

  setActive(value: bool) { // return type should be class if instance
    this._active = value
    return this
  }
}

class MySub extends MyClass {
  // something
}
```

How should I define the return type for `setActive()` if it may return MyClass or any of the SubClasses? Is `MyClass` also correct for subclasses?

Comment: It returns `MyClass`

Comment: Not obviously, it can also be asubclass.

Comment: A subclass of `MyClass` is also an instance of `MyClass`. That's the nature of subclasses.

Comment: But then flow won't let me call methods from `MySub` on the returned instance from `MyClass.setActive()` :-(

Comment: There's a word for this type relationship (where a generic function returns the same type it was called on), but I can't remember it. It's not covariance or contravariance, but I think it's something like that. I glanced at the Flow documentation and don't see anything that allows you to express it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so far I got the answer after asking the same in as issue for flow: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4135

So the returned flow type should be also defined as `this`.

```
// @flow
class MyClass {

  _active: bool

  setActive(value: bool): this { 
    this._active = value
    return this
  }
}

class MySub extends MyClass {
  // something
}
```